# How can I optimize this query and make it execute faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

How would I get faster results with this query?

```
SELECT
    post_id
FROM
    wp_postmeta
WHERE
    meta_key='wpcf-cooler-name' AND (
        post_id IN (
            SELECT 
                post_id
            FROM
                wp_postmeta
            WHERE
                meta_key='wpcf-cooler-name' AND
                meta_value LIKE '%sosa%' AND (
                    post_id IN (
                        SELECT
                            object_id AS 'post_id'
                        FROM
                            wp_term_relationships
                        WHERE 
                            term_taxonomy_id=227
                    )
                ) AND (
                    post_id IN (
                        SELECT
                            ID AS 'post_id'
                        FROM
                            wp_posts
                        WHERE 
                            post_type='cooler' AND
                            post_status='publish'
                    )
                )
        )
    ) ORDER BY meta_value ASC
```

My database has more than 15000 entries. Therefore it takes time to show results.

Comment: can't you use JOINs instead of subqueries? Also, make sure all your relevant fields are indexed, like `meta_key`, `post_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`...

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a bunch of WordPress table and column names?

Answer (score 3):

Using `WHERE` conditions:

```
SELECT
  post.id
FROM
  wp_posts as post, wp_postmeta as postmeta, wp_term_relationships as relationships
WHERE
  postmeta.meta_key='wpcf-cooler-name'
  AND postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%sosa%'
  AND relationships.object_id = post.post_id
  AND relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 227
  AND post.ID = postmeta.post_id
  AND post.post_type = 'cooler'
  AND post.post_status='publish'
ORDER BY postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT wp.post_id 
FROM wp_postmeta wp 
INNER JOIN (SELECT object_id AS 'post_id' 
            FROM wp_term_relationships 
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 227 
        UNION  
            SELECT ID AS 'post_id' 
            FROM wp_posts 
            WHERE post_type = 'cooler' AND post_status = 'publish') A ON wp.post_id = A.post_id
WHERE wp.meta_key = 'wpcf-cooler-name' AND wp.meta_value LIKE '%sosa%' 
ORDER BY wp.meta_value;
```